# .desktop file on dock opens in another instance for unity/android studio

Tags: unity, gnome, launcher, icons, .desktop

[this is what it happens when I try to open unity/android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oC94X.png)

I made two desktop files for them in /usr/share/applications

This is the unity.desktop file

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Unity
Exec=/home/toor/Downloads/unity/UnityHub.AppImage
Icon=/usr/share/icons/unity.jpg
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
MimeType=text/plain;
Categories=Development;Application;
Keywords=Unity;Games;
```

and android studio

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Android Studio
Exec=studio.sh
Icon=/home/toor/Downloads/android-studio/bin/studio.svg
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
MimeType=text/plain;
Categories=Development;Application;
Keywords=Android Studio;Flutter;Apps;
```

What is the additional line I must add for it to open in the same instance not another one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer for Android studio

Instead of making a manual desktop file for it you can go to

`Android Studio -> Tools -> Create Desktop Entry`

and for the unity hub as it's an AppImage

you can use [AppImaged](https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit/releases) for appimages